# Accepting a linq null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query here that is done with entity framework. The query will return null every once in a while. So I had to write the linq query to accept this null. However this doesn't work. The if statement (viewsByUdHours != null) returns true then still executes the lines of code in the if statement.

```
       DateTime startDateTimeHours = now.AddHours(-24);

       var viewsByIdHours = db.ArticleViews
            .Where(av => av.ViewCreated >= startDateTimeHours)
            .GroupBy(av => av.ArticleID)
            .Select(g => new { ArticleID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

        if (viewsByIdHours != null)
        {
            var highestCountHours = viewsByIdHours.Max(v => v.Count);

            var topArticlesHours = viewsByIdHours.Where(a => a.Count == highestCountHours);

            var topArticleHours = topArticlesHours.First();

            var articleTitleHours = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ID == topArticleHours.ArticleID).Select(x => x.title).First();

            ViewBag.activityDay = articleTitleHours + " (" + topArticleHours.Count + ")";
        }
        else
            ViewBag.activityDay = "NaN";
```

I get this error at the "`var highestCountHours = viewsByIdHours.Max(v => v.Count);`" line:

```
The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. 
Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

Comment: viewByIdHours will never be null. change your if statement to `viewByIdHours.Any()`

Comment: np, the variable viewByIdHours just holds the query (not sure of the exact type) and the query will never be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewByIdHours` will never be null. change your if statement to `viewByIdHours.Any()`.  the variable `viewByIdHours` just holds the query and the query will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help. As you have a null:

```
var viewsByIdHours = db.ArticleViews
        .Where(av => av.ViewCreated >= startDateTimeHours)
        .GroupBy(av => av.ArticleID)
        .Select(g => new { ArticleID = g.Key, Count = g.Count()??0 });
```

So if your field `Count` is null then it will be 0;